# EntityFramework CodeFirst Mapping to have camel case in the database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've just started a new company who are happy for me to use CodeFirst - but want the database fields camel cased.

I'm currently writing a lot of this kind of stuff ...

```
    [Column("active")]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [Column("paymentType")]
    public string PaymentType { get; set; }
```

Is there any way I can just set it all to Camel Case the database, rather than having to decorate all my properties?

Thanks

Comment: camel case your POCO members ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [code first custom conventions](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Conventions)
If using Fluent Api, you could alternatively use reflection of each Type in your context.
Loop on each POCO and and for each PROPERTY set the name changing char1 to lowercase.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EFTestPoco>().Property(p=>p.UoM1).HasColumnName("camelCase");
```

**EDIT:**  The Reflection challenge includes dynamic lambda...
Until you asked I didnt realise that the loop required dynamic lambda....
Opened my mouth too wide :-)

... This is a cut and paste from pieces of code i use.
... I use the EASIER /System.Linq.Dynamic approach

You can use the Expression Complication library [System.Linq.Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.aspx) 
or You can use the easier to use  [Dynamic Lambda library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/bb894665.aspx) 
to build dymanic Linq statements.
**SO here is the sample code**

```
  // inside your context on model creating
  //....   
 // repeat for each poco.  // or reflect on thr context if feeling lazy and intellectual
 var entity = new EntityTypeConfiguration<Poco>;
// Get the properties of a poco
    foreach (var propInfo in typeof(T).GetProperties()) {
            SetCamelCase<T>(propInfo,entity);
        }
 modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(entity);
 ....
 } // end of ON model creating



private static void SetCamelCase<TModelPoco>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, 
                             EntityTypeConfiguration<TModelPoco> entity) where TModelPoco : BaseObject {

        var camel = propertyInfo.Name.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + propertyInfo.Name.Substring(1);

        switch (propertyInfo.UnderLyingType().Name) {
            case SystemDataTypeConstants.String :
            var propLambdaString = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<TModelPoco, string >(propertyInfo.Name);
            entity.Property(propLambdaString).HasColumnName(camel);
            break;
            case SystemDataTypeConstants.Int32:
            var propLambdaInt =System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<TModelPoco, int >(propertyInfo.Name);
            entity.Property(propLambdaInt).HasColumnName(camel);
                break;
           //  SystemDataTypeConstants. // and teh rest you may use...
        }


    }
    public static Type UnderLyingType(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo) {
        return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfo.PropertyType) ?? propertyInfo.PropertyType;
    }
```

Comment: I'd be happy enough doing your second suggestion but there is no "Properties" off Entity<> - only Property with a property selector.  How do I actually iterate through the properties?  Thanks